# How to view drive files in my application with an access token of my mail without end user login with their mail

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a web application which is configured with my mail id. I have functionality of  view google drive files in screen. Any user who logged in my site able to view the drive file (located in my mail id).But it is working only if the end user login with Gmail in the same browser. I want my application should work with my mail id that i configured in my system. Every user who logged into my site should able to view the drive file even though they don't have any permission to the drive file. Also I don't want my drive files should be public.so that any one with link cannot view the files. Am using google drive php client v3 for it. I didn't find any code samples regarding this. Any help/clarification is appreciated guys really

Comment: `Every user who logged into my site should able to view the drive file even though they don't have any permission to the drive file. `...this is a simple contradiction and is not really solveable

Answer (score 1):

> I have a web application which is configured with my mail id.

I would be intrested to know how you have achived this,  I suspect that you mean you logged in your application using Oauth2 and are running it with the same Oauth2 token.

> I have functionality of view google drive files in screen.

I suspect that you mean you can open this file in the Google drive web application.  Probably using the weblink from the file.get response.

> Any user who logged in my site able to view the drive file (located in my mail id). But it is working only if the end user login with Gmail in the same browser.

Just because your application using the google drive api using your credentials with Oauth2 does not mean that the weblink will open for anyone but you or someone who has been granted access.  Anyone who wants to view the file will still have either access to login to your account or have permission on the file from their own google drive account.

I do not recommend you give everyone  the login and password to your google account.

> I want my application should work with my mail id that i configured in my system.

This is not possible you might be able to get around it using a service account with domain wide delegation to a workspace account but its still only going to give you Google drive api access. It will not give a random person access to a file on your drive account.  As the Google drive web application will only show a file that the user has access to.

> Every user who logged into my site should able to view the drive file even though they don't have any permission to the drive file.

This may be possible if you set the file to public.

> Also I don't want my drive files should be public.

You need to understand the difference between private and public data.  Private data is owned by someone, and to get access to that you must have the permission of that person.  In order to get permission to access a google drive file if you don't want to set it public you will need to share the file with this person.

> so that any one with link cannot view the files.

In that case the file is private and you will need to share it with them.

> Am using google drive php client v3 for it. I didn't find any code samples regarding this.

That is because what you want to do is not possible.

## comments.

In order to access a file stored on Google drive someone needs to have access to it.  Even if you set the file public I suspect the user will still need to be logged into their own google drive account.

Google drive is a file storage system its not meant for file hosting in your application.

Even using a service account will not help you in this case as it sounds like you want to open the file in the google drive web application.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I am using https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php  for iplementing upload,delete,and view. In my application iam configuring tmy gmail account through php code.accesstoken and everything will be saved in db.WHen user logins to my site. The files uploaded through above api's are showing in another screen using preview of google drive.But i want to show based on the accesstoken from my mail id but not with their login as  we dont give access to that files to their drive

Comment: That sample is already single user as it uses a static $tokenPath which stores your access token in it when it runs if you never change it then it will only connect to your account.  Your issue is the part where you want to "show" the file to the user.  If you want to do this using the Google drive web application then its not going to work to use the Google drive web application you will need to have access to the file and that can not be granted using the Oauth2 method used in the Google drive api it simply doesnt wokr that way.